# Google Apps and OAuth best practices

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-apps

I am working on integrating Google Apps into my PHP app. I have already a login system that assigns a session ID to a user (after entering username and password), which gets stored in the database when the user is logged in. Session ID's become invalid after a certain time of inactivity (configurable by the user, can be 5 minutes, 15, 60...). That session ID is passed in the url to check if a user is still logged in. When logging out, the session ID is removed from the database.

I let people log in with Google by storing their Google ID in the database, when they log in, I request an access token, query the userinfo, see if the google ID is in the database and if so, assign a session ID to this user. Since I want to be able to query other API's I also store the access token json in the database. When a user logs out, the access token is also removed from the database.

This works, my users are able to log in using their Google account and I can query the API's using the stored access_token, however some things feel clunky of make me feel uncertain about my workflow:

- If you force_approval you get a refresh_token, I feel like I should be using this refresh token to get a new access token, instead of removing the old one from the database and entering a new one when the user logs in again. On the other hand, when logging in, I do not know who it is yet, so I don't know which refresh token to use. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what the refresh token is for. Also, I don't really want to force approval every time, so I can't even use the refresh_token in that case.
- As said before, users can determine how long their session will last, however, the google access_token always expires after 3600 seconds. It'd be really stupid if users would work an hour on the system and after that the Google API's suddenly fail, forcing them to log in again.  The Google OAuth playground shows a checkbox "Auto-refresh token before it expires", but I'm not seeing how to do this. Do I have to use the refresh token here? Or simply request a new token in the background (if I'm not forcing approval)?
- At the moment, I'm using the userinfo query (https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo) to find the user id, but I can also use the tokeninfo (https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo). Tokeninfo is not listed in the oauth playground, but the result does show how long the token remains valid (however, I can also calculate this myself). Is one preferable over the other?
- I'm storing the entire json object in the database (access_token, id_token, expires_in and token_type) but I feel my app will still work perfectly if I only store the access_token (only problem I foresee is if the expires_in time changes). Do I need to store the id_token for example?

I find the Google documentation (at developers.google.com) sometimes very lacking, if anyone knows any other good sources of information, I'm interested in them as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it might help if you took a look at the lastest [OpenID Connect Specs](http://openid.net/connect/) where concepts like the userinfo endpoint come from. OpenID connect is built on top of OAuth 2. There's quite a lot in there, but it's still probably worth a look. [This blog article](http://www.thread-safe.com/2012/02/designing-single-sign-on-system-using.html) is also very good (as are others in the same blog).

Unfortunately, I don't think Google's implementation is currently up to date with the latest spec draft so it will probably be a moving target for some time. These things have changed a lot over the past year.

I agree with your first point that you should be obtaining a new access token each time you authenticate a user, rather than refreshing an old one. You don't know who the user is until they have logged in and granted you an access token. In general, the lifespan of an access token is not linked to the user's session. Once issued, your application could theoretically use it to access resources independently of the user's presence. If you want to carry on accessing the resource beyond the token expiry time, then you need to submit the refresh token at that point to obtain a new access token. I'm afraid I don't know what the "auto-refresh" feature is for.

I believe Google's `tokeninfo` is analogous to the `check_id` endpoint of OpenID connect, but accepts either an access token or an id token, rather than just the latter. Note that the expiry times of the two may differ. You would typically be able to retrieve more detailed user data from the `userinfo` endpoint than from `check_id`, which would normally return the bare `user_id`.

You shouldn't need to store the `id_token`. It is a bit like a record of the user's authentication by the authorization server. The access token is what your application will be interested in maintaining once you have validated the user identity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, I will read the articles you provided and hope they will help me along the way.